# XCode - copying localy all external files linked into the project

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, xcode4, project

When I made my project, I've added many files just by link, without copying them into the project folder. But now, I'd like to have a pack that include all the necessary files into the project folder.

How can I make all those external files being copied into the project folder without having to check them one by one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

1. Delete all the files from your project.
2. Geather all the files you want to copy.
3. Drag them all together to your project again, and now check the "Copy item to the destination folder"

I believe this is the fastest way to do this.

Comment: Assuming you know the files that are linked and those who aren't. And this is not the case...

Comment: Does the files located in different folders on your mac ? If so then the only way that I can think of is to cut the files that are in your app folder and copy them to an other temp folder. all the red (missing file names on your app will be the ones that are linked, all the others are not. Then you can add all your not-linked files to the temp folder and finally drag all the files to your app again. There is no magic that know of. How many files do you have there?

Comment: That seems to be a good way to do this if no built-in method is available.

Comment: Can you update your answer with your comment so I can accept it ?